# can't get the string from enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to get the result of my enum for a location as a string but for some reason, it's only showing it as an integer in the index page.

**Model**

```
public class UserLicense
{
    [Key]
public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

**Enum Class**

```
public enum LocationType
{
    Brazil,
    USA,
    UK
    //etc .. here i will add around another 30 items
}
```

**Controller**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(IFormCollection col)
        {
            if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            UserLicense uc = new UserLicense();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    DateTime? ends = null;
                    if (DateTime.TryParse(col["ends"], out DateTime tmp)) ends = tmp;
                    string username = col["user.username"].ToString().Normalize();
                    var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NormalizedUsername == username);
                    uc = new UserLicense
                    {
                        Ends = ends,
                        Starts = DateTime.Parse(col["starts"]),
                        UserId = user.Id,
                        LicenseId = int.Parse(col["licenseid"]),
                        Location = Enum.GetName(typeof(LocationType),col["Location"]), //the issue is here.           
                    };
                    _context.Add(uc);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

**Create HTML**

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Location" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="Location" class="form-control" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<LocationType>()"></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="Location" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried the ToString() method for enums?

Comment: yes i tried and it didn't work unfortunatly.

Comment: @MomenAlnaser, If col["Location"] is an integer, you should correctly get string name of the enum. Have you tried debugging the code? Maybe the problem is somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using **`IFormCollection`** to transfer the parameters to the controller, not matter using `public string Location { get; set; }`  or `public string Location { get; set; }`, in the controller the Location value in the IFormCollection will be always an integer. So, you could based on the int value to get string value from the Enum:

```
var location = ((LocationType)int.Parse(col["location"])).ToString();
```

The result like this:

[image]

Besides, there has another solution, you could use the Strongly typed data (use UserLicense model in the action method, instead of IFormCollection) to transfer the parameter to the controller.

Code like this:

```
public class UserLicense
{
    [Key]
    public int License { get; set; }
    public DateTime Ends { get; set; }
    public DateTime Starts { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public LocationType Location { get; set; }
}
    public enum LocationType
    {
        Brazil, 
        USA,
        UK
    }
```

and

```
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    } 
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(UserLicense userLicense)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var location = userLicense.Location;

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Code in the Create.cshtml:

```
    @model WebApplication1.Models.UserLicense

    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h1>Create</h1>

    <h4>UserLicense</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form asp-action="Create">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="License" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="License" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="License" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Ends" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Ends" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Ends" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Starts" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Starts" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Starts" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="UserId" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="UserId" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="UserId" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Location" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="Location" class="form-control" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<LocationType>()"></select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Location" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]

Comment: I did the same here but the result shows null instead of showing the sting as UK in your case.
and anyhow, there are still an error in Location = uc.Location as it always select the first value

Comment: @MomenAlnaser I have posted the whole sample code,  you could check it. In the Create action you are using UserLicense, instead of IFormCollection right? Try to rebuild your application and clear the cache, then check whether it works or not?

Comment: @MomenAlnaser From your original post, I notice that you are creating a new Userlicense in the Create method: ` UserLicense uc = new UserLicense();`, try to set a break point before it, and check the input parameters (in my sample code, check the userLicense), perhaps you are getting location from the new instance instead of from the input parameters.

Comment: you are right, im getting it from the new instance and it's always getting the first value

Comment: it get solved, thank you so much > I have used your below code inside the new instance
Location = ((LocationType)int.Parse(col["location"]))

Answer (score 1):

Make your `Location` property a type of `LocationType` instead of `string`.

```
public class UserLicense
{
    [Key]
    public LocationType Location { get; set; }
}
```

Pass Location to the view from the `Create` action like this

```
uc = new UserLicense
{
    Ends = ends,
    Starts = DateTime.Parse(col["starts"]),
    UserId = user.Id,
    LicenseId = int.Parse(col["licenseid"]),
    Location = uc.Location          
};
```

Then in the view

```
<select asp-for="Location" class="form-control" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<LocationType>()">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Please Select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: after adding it i had to add using System.Text.Json.Serialization; as a reference but also it didn't work

Comment: @MomenAlnaser Check the modified answer.

Comment: you mean Location=uc.location  NOT user; any how it didnt even open the page and it shows InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Int32'.

Comment: @MomenAlnaser Run migrations again from package manager console. Do `add-migration migration_name`, then `update-databse`. If that doesn't work, place a break point to know exactly where the `InvalidCastException` is coming from.

Comment: Or you might need to drop the database with `drop-database` because there are rows already with a type of string in the Location column. The database will be confused with multiple types. If the database already has important data, just preserve the previous location column of type string , so you will have two properties but you wont be needing the other one anymore like this. `public string LocationOld` and `public LocationType Location`

Comment: yeah I understand but unfortunately, I have an issue with PMC it's not working fine, so i will fix it and try the upon instructions, thank you so much